# How did John Lennon tune his guitar

Tags: guitar, tuning

From the Wikipedia page on the quarrymen: [The Quarrymen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quarrymen).

> Lennon's mother, Julia Lennon, taught her son to play the banjo and then showed Lennon and Eric Griffiths how to tune their guitars in a similar way to the banjo, and taught them simple chords and songs.

My question is how did he tune and did he do so with the Beatles as well?

Comment: Unverified sources on the internet suggest that he initially used only 5 strings on his guitar and tuned it like a banjo (probably open-G), but that all but a handful of Beatles songs (such as Dear Prudence) were recorded using standard tuning.

Comment: It's more common to tune a banjo like the top strings of a guitar!

Answer (score 4):

"tuning the guitars a similar way to the banjo" is a reference to open tuning, usually open G.

This was relatively common in Blues and American old time music (from which skiffle was largely derived), and it's easy to play some basic chords for beginners on it too (easier to "get going", so to speak, whereas with standard tuning it's much easier to make some quite cacophonous sounds if your left hand isn't yet up to scratch)

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that Julia was the first to teach a few chords to John, but I've also read the when George joined the band, John stood onstage with his guitar, only faking his playing, and that George was the person who really taught John to play. The only person still living that might be able to set the record straight is probably Paul.

Comment: The question surely is more about the actual tuning notes rather than who taught whom.

Comment: @Tim- I suppose I should have been a little more precise in my answer. Perhaps Julia taught John to tune like a banjo, and then George came along and taught him standard tuning and open tunings since that was Georges area of expertise. That's the point I was trying to get across, I hope I have a little better success this time.

Comment: Speaking of faking the playing, the first audible playing by John appears on 'All my Loving'. Before that I really cannot hear a note he plays.

Comment: @user207421- That's what I call pulling something apart to look at it!  I've listened to a lot of Beatles, but I never pulled any of it apart like that. I'll have to try it sometime to see if I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Lennon's mom taught him a few banjo chords ..He tuned his gtr like a banjo..When G. Harrison saw him play..he said "What are you doing w 5 strings" from that point George came to the rescue and straightened his ass out..The advantage of JL's position as ryth gtr player shows on "All My Loving" and "Dear Prudence" George and Paul envied JLs finger picking techniques..And
"Revolution" is another example how JL killed no matter how he tuned..Yeah The Beatles taught each other no doubt..and Paul was a workaholic..They were great together..and just regular apart.

Comment: Please use full words. Do you have any citations for this?

Answer (score 2):

What's interesting, John Lennon purposely tuned the D string low on his guitar making it "slightly out of tune" in order to make it recognizable on mono recordings from the other Beatles. He did the same on a few occasions when he played live on his [1961 Hofner](https://bestguitarsnow.com/history-of-hofner-guitars-all-you-need-to-know/) bass.

You can hear it on the video below:

[John Lennon Out Of Tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SqAahel-ws&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2F&feature=emb_title)